# Which trait bound should I use for a type that must implement the "iter" function

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to implement a struct composed of a generic field which type must implement the non-consuming "iter" method (see below).

```
struct Node<T> {
    key: T
}

impl<T> Node<T> where T: ?? {
    fn do_stuff(&self) {
        for e in self.key.iter() {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n1 = Node { key: "foo".to_owned() };
    n1.do_stuff();
    
    let n2 = Node { key: vec![1, 2, 3] };
    n2.do_stuff();
}
```

Which trait bound should I associate with the parameter `T`?

Answer (score 6):

The trait bound you're looking for is `&T: IntoIterator`. By convention, types that provide a non-consuming `iter()` also provide an implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&T`. (Likewise, `iter_mut()` comes in pair with an impl of `IntoIterator` for `&mut T`.)

So, while you won't be able to literally call `iter()`, you'll be able to iterate over standard-library containers such as `Vec`, `HashMap`, etc., without consuming them:

```
impl<T> Node<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator,
{
    fn do_stuff(&self) {
        for e in &self.key { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f24493a5c284232d4a75fe9c3e387b3)

Note that the above won't accept `key: "foo".to_owned()` simply because Rust strings are not iterable.

Answer (score 3):

> Which trait bound should I associate with the parameter `T`?

There is no such a trait in the standard library, the [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) is an *inherent method* – it doesn't come from a trait implementation. You could, of course, create your own trait (e.g., `Iter`) that specifies `iter()`.

If you are working with a generic type and need to ensure that such type's values can be turned into an iterator, you may want to consider bounding the type to the [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't ```IntoIterator``` consuming?

Comment: Not if you pass a reference. The `IntoIterator` instance on `&'a Vec<T>`, for instance, "consumes" the immutable reference, but immutable references are `Copy` so that consumption is meaningless.